# Jersey Rest Service not working using Json annotaion

Tags: java, json, rest, api, jersey

I have the following classes:
ServerStartup.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.sun.jersey.api.container.httpserver.HttpServerFactory;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.core.ResourceConfig;
import com.sun.jersey.api.json.JSONConfiguration;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class ServerStartUp {
static final String BASE_URI = "http://localhost:9999/";
public static void main(String[] args) {


    try {
        final ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.twins.engine");
        rc.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);         
        HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(BASE_URI,rc);
        server.setExecutor(null);
        server.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

and the following class SysInfo.Java

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.twins.engine.model.SysInfo;

@Path("/Sys")
public class General {

@GET
@Path("/info")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public SysInfo getInfo(){
    SysInfo info = new SysInfo("Monetoring 365");
    return info;
}
}
```

and the following model class SysInfo.java

```
public class SysInfo {
private String name;
public SysInfo(String name) {
    this.setName(name);
}

public String getName() {return name;}

public void setName(String name) {this.name = name; }
}
```

When i run the serverStartup class and Navigate to the following url:
http://127.0.0.1:9999/sys/info

i got the following exception:

Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.MessageException: A message body writer for Java class com.twins.engine.model.SysInfo, and Java type class com.twins.engine.model.SysInfo, and MIME media type text/html was not found
    ... 15 more

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJBQf.png)as well i have the following Jars attached as image, is there any missing configuration i have to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following

```
final ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.twins.engine");
final Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<String, Object>();
config.put("com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature", true);
rc.setPropertiesAndFeatures(config);
HttpServer server = HttpServerFactory.create(BASE_URI,rc);
server.setExecutor(null);
server.start();
```

and probably you have to add jackson-mapper

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I try the changes you added but it is not working giving the same exception error

Comment: @Twinscode how do you run the application? and can you past your pom.xml

Comment: I run the main in ServerStartup.java

Comment: The whole project posted in the issue description and i do not have a pom.xml file

Comment: fine, probably you may be running with your ide, wondering if you have jars correctly in classpath

Comment: [List of Jars](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IJBQf.png) the Jars I have in the link plus the and jackson-core-asl, jackson-mapper-asl jars